# IE Compatibility Issue Dynamic Loading Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, compatibility

I am generating Dynamic Vertical Menu using Jquery Ajax.

The Code is working fine with Chrome, Firefox but it is not loading using IE. I am new to web development and Browser compatibility issues of IE.

The Demo Link is at pumpit.in
See the loader in the left menu. It is not appearing in IE. If you reload the Link, it may come.

The js code used is :

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "Index.aspx/wmCommSubComm",
    data: jsonData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#container_leftns').html('<img src="/images/loading123.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
        //return false;
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        //retData = msg.d;
        $('#container_leftns').html(msg.d);
        return false;
    },
    error: function () {
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        //$('#Attri_left-div').html('<p><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
    }
});
```

If anybody could guide me it would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve data that is in a sub-domain or cross domain?

Comment: You have include js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js twice, try remove one.

Comment: IE version.....6,7,8,9,10.......?

Comment: @james : Yes the data is coming from cross domain.

Comment: @Derek : I will try removing the duplicate entry but is this the cause, As the loader gif is also not showing in the IE.

Comment: @Jai : It is not working on IE 9 and earlier, not tested on 10

Comment: @PankajSharma You mentioned up `Yes the data is coming from cross domain` but url doesn't seem to be like that.

Comment: @jai: some of the image data is placed on different url but the left menu is loaded from the ajax using database on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the result from your ajax call, you are returning some HTML5 elements such as "section". It works nicely in Firefox/Chrome and IE9. However, HTML5 tags are not supported for the version that less than IE9. They cannot recognize HTML5 tags. Please note that not all HTML5 are supported in IE9. Ref: [HTML5 tags in IE9](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-support-ie9/)

For the version less then IE9, you can help them to recognize the HTML5 tags by including javascript fix [html5shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) / from github [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv).
-OR-
Change change the HTML5 tags to div instead.

Regarding to fix the loading image, I think we would do this work around.

HTML - Preload the loading image to the container and display it

```
<div id="container_leftns_loading" class="container_leftns">
    <img src="http://pumpit.in/images/loading123.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
<div id="container_leftns"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Index.aspx/wmCommSubComm",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        // use show instead and clear the leftns container
        $('#container_leftns_loading').show();
        $('#container_leftns').html('');
        //return false;
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        // hide the loading image when success
        $('#container_leftns_loading').hide();
        $('#container_leftns').html(msg.d);
        return false;
    },
    error: function () {
        // failed request; give feedback to user
        //$('#Attri_left-div').html('<p><strong>Oops!</strong> Try that again in a few moments.</p>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, I tried using html5shiv but it is not working. The Loader image that should come before loading is also missing. I trying to change section to div and will let you know the result. If any more suggestion let me know.

Comment: I also changed section to div, no change. I have uploaded the updated code. Any help will be appreciated. The Problem is also that the loader gif is also not coming which visible in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Added a work around fix, see if it can fix the problem in IE.

Comment: Thanks Derek, It fixed the image loading  problem, but the dynamic content is not coming. I have also removed double jquery download. I have uploaded the latest code on the server.
There is also one more erratic behavior. If you open for the first time, the menu gets loaded but if you refresh it it does not load after that.
Thanks for the help. Hope you can guide me some more.

Comment: May I know the reason why set `async:false`? It should be true if you want an asynchronize request.

Comment: One more observation when using the debugging of index.js and you add break point on success function where $('#container_leftns').html(msg.d); The values come right but it is not added in Dom.

Comment: I have try to modify the inner content in msg.d by `msg.d = msg.d.replace(/article/gi,'div')`. Then it shows, so I guess it should related to the new HTML5 tag `article`, try change it to `div`

Comment: I changed the article tag with div but no effect.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue in IE8 after you change it to div. Now, I can see the menu every time.

Comment: Yes I changed the browser mode to IE8 and IE7 it is loading everytime. But have some issue in IE9 and it is not visible.

Comment: I can see the menu in IE9 also. But the slide show and right column is disappear. Try to clear your browser cache. 
PS: Remember to vote the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the patient support. I think I have remove HTML5 tags for the site running on IE.

Comment: I have made changes to the code and removed the HTML5 tags but the centre content still not loading in IE 9. I have uploaded the latest code on pumpit.in.

Comment: and one more issue is that the site is opening on my localhost.